# JSON array href as a variable in jQuery

Tags: json, function, variables, jquery

I have a getJSON function that converts the results to an html template to display as a list that contains a different hyperlink within each list item. I need to override the normal html function of the link so it doesn't open a new page but loads into a specific divide using the load() method located within my navClickListener() function.

If I put a dummy url into `var gotoURL = '';//<--..AND GET THE ITEMS LINK INTO THIS VAR...`, it works as planned but I need to grab the actual url's from the array items.

I cannot figure a way to do this. Can you please look thru my snippets and pay attention to the inline comments in all CAPS.

Thank-you for your help.

```
function loadNav(url, container, appendE) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){

            $.each(data.items, function(){
                var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();
                // Now fill in the fields with the data
                . . . .
                newItem.find("a").attr("href", this.gotoURL);//<--PREVENT NORMAL FUNCTION...
                // And add the new list item to the page
                newItem.children().appendTo('#' + appendE)
            });
            . . . .
            // Click listener for navigation items
            var target = data.targetKey;
            var gotoURL = '';//<--..AND GET THE ITEMS LINK INTO THIS VAR...
            navClickListener(appendE, target, gotoURL);
        });
    };

    /* ========== Navigation click listener function ============= */   
    function navClickListener(appendE, target, gotoURL) {
        $('#' + appendE).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
             $('#' + target).load(gotoURL);//<--...SO IT GETS INTO HERE??
             . . . .
        });
    };
```

Comment: Everything works to the point of needing a variable to catch the hyperlink.

Comment: `newItem.find("a").attr("href")` will get you the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: @Rocket Tried that earlier and didn't work. Thnx

Comment: is your gotoURL a string? maybe try

newItem.find("a").attr("href", this.gotoURL.toString());

http://jsfiddle.net/colemande/QK4gp/7/

Comment: @colemande Could you expand on that? And put and example in an answer? This way I can get a better understanding.  Thnx. EDIT Basically link it all up and where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this I found was to do an inline JavaScript in the href witch required changing the gotoURL row in the database to: `javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent', 'http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content');` This is important that its inline to maintain the double-quotes at the ends when `newItem.find("a").attr("href", this.gotoURL);` is executed in a `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )` function. Any other type of methode of inline javaScript will not work!! (ie: `javascript:void(0);" onclick='javascript:navClickListener("navContent", "bodyContent" "http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content");')` <--See the end-quote before *onClick*.

Additional script changes from above:

REMOVED:

```
var gotoURL = '';//<--..AND GET THE ITEMS LINK INTO THIS VAR...
navClickListener(appendE, target, gotoURL);
```

Changed the navClickListener() function to:

```
function navClickListener(target, gotoURL) {
    $('#' + target).load(gotoURL);
};
```

Changed database data in gotoURL from:

```
/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content
```

to:

```
javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent', 'http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm tired of the adding more comments thing it kept posting when I hit enter.

I guess what I was trying to say is that I don't know where your gotoURL is coming from. I would try putting a dummy url in there for a test to see if your URL updates. If it does then your gotoURL is the problem.

```
newItem.find("a").attr("href", "IAmtesting.com")
```

also here is some [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/colemande/QK4gp/7)

Comment: It comes from a JSON array via php, pulled from a database. That part works. I need to override the normal href and then extract the link (as a string?) to put it into a variable so I can send it to an html div, not a new window.