# Proper Syntax to Pass Vars in a href JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

Basic question so I feel dumb but..., Whats the proper syntax below in the href?

The href:

```
<html>
<a href="javascript:navClickListener("navContent", "bodyContent" "http://somelink.com");"></a>
</html>
```

The Function:

```
function navClickListener(appendE, target, gotoURL) {
    //doing stuff
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you really have to use inline JavaScript, use different quotes, eg `'` or `&quot;`.
Currently, the HTML attributes are marked by double quotes, as well as the JavaScript code.

```
<a href="javascript:navClickListener("navContent", "bodyContent" "http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content");"></a>
Is effectively truncated to:
<a href="javascript:navClickListener("></a>
                                     ^ Because of this.
```

In this case, since you're using a JavaScript-**URI**, you can also use `%22` instead of double quotes.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pu3CM/

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off avoiding JavaScript in your "href" attributes.

```
<a href='#' onclick='navClickListener("navContent", "bodyContent", "http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content"); return false;'>Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Actually needed it inline to keep the double-quotes at the ends. See why in my [SO? here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9949340/742030)

Answer (score 1):

Using `javascript:void(0);` as the HREF value will prevent jumping or other undesired behavior from happening when the user clicks on the anchor. Use single quotes since you have double quotes in your JavaScript.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='javascript:navClickListener("navContent", "bodyContent" "http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive #content");'></a>
```

Alternatively, you can do the entire thing in your JavaScript by binding a click handler. This would allow you to set a normal HREF value, which would be better for screen readers, and still allow the same functionality.

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.34/wiki/index.php/Airworthiness_Directive#content" class="someclass"></a>

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.someclass').click( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();//Does the same thing as javascript:void(0); in the HREF value
        var pageURL = $(this).attr('href');
        navClickListener("navContent", "bodyContent", pageURL );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thats what I was originally was trying to do. See this [SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9949340/742030) if you can help?? Thnx